# Why is end to end testing needed?

Tags: functional, end-to-end

Isn't end to end already tested when you do different levels of functional tests?

For example:
1. Test A -> B (but to do this, need to do x -> z)
2. Test C -> F (but to do this, need to do A -> B)
3. and so on...

Comment: It is unclear what are you asking for. What A, B, x, z, C, F are?

Comment: Somehow related question explaining what integration tests do (as end-to-end testing is a form of integration testing): http://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/5131/how-does-system-testing-differ-from-system-integration-testing-sit

Answer (score 2):

We need end-to-end testing because our assumptions about how components interact are never completely accurate.

You might also ask why we need to test A->B if we're testing A->B->...->Z.  Testing A->B by themselves helps with *diagnosis* because we can narrow down any bugs to A, B, and interactions between A and B.

Comment: Aren't functional tests testing interactions between components? ;-) In other words, what's the difference between functional tests and end-to-end tests? I guess that's rather a question to OP what he or she had in mind.

Comment: Put another way, the inputs at the beginning of each of the functional tests may not accurately reflect real-world conditions.